# How to make all child elements red

Tags: javascript, html

This is the html code:

```
<div id="sm-responsive-one">
  <p> Step one </p>
  <div  style="">1</div>
  <div  style="">2</div>
  <div  style="">3</div>
  <div  style="">4</div>
</div>

<div id="sm-responsive-two">
  <p> Step two </p>
  <div  style="">5</div>
  <div  style="">6</div>
  <div  style="">7</div>
  <div  style="">8</div>
</div>
```

Problem: I want to make 1,2,3 and 4 (child element of `sm-responsive-one` read color using JavaScript and without using any loop. Is it possible?

This is the code I am trying:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("sm-responsive-one").getElementsByTagName("div").style.color="red";

  //document.getElementById("sm-responsive-one").getElementsByTagName("div")[2].style.color="red";
</script>
```

Comment: Why use JavaScript and not CSS?

Comment: Because, I want to make it dynamic for my project.

Comment: Dynamic how? This would seem very basic with CSS as you've presented it.

Comment: Yes, it a very little part of the comple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add this CSS rule:

```
.red-children div  {color: red}
```

Then the javascript is:

```
document.getElementById('sm-responsive-one').className = "red-children"
```

Comment: You should add the `red-children` class to the classList, if you can.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a loop, as `getElements*` return pseudo-arrays.

If you don't want to use the literal loop syntax, you could apply `Array.prototype.forEach`, but that's still a loop internally.

```
var children = document.getElementById("sm-responsive-one").getElementsByTagName("div");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function (it) {
    it.style.color="red";
});
```

Comment: This reminds me of the "I don't want to use a loop" question where 9 answers technically used loops

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns HTML elements collection, so you need to iterate over them:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("sm-responsive-one").getElementsByTagName("div");

for( var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    elements[ i ].style.color = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#sm-responsive-one > div").css("color","red");
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6xxws1z/

Comment: It will make all element red. Not just inside div.

Comment: @Adam Smith No It will make only elements red which are inside the #sm-responsive-one

Comment: It will be also red "Step one" . but it should not be red.

Comment: @Adam Smith Read the question properly In that Problem: I want to make 1,2,3 and 4 (child element of sm-responsive-one read color using JavaScript and without using any loop. Is it possible?